# Question about computing $5^{64} \pmod{193}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How to compute $5^{64} \pmod{193}$?

My idea was:

$5^{64} = (5^4)^{16} \equiv 625^{16} \equiv 46^{16}\pmod{193}$.

Now I don't understand why it's $46^{16} \equiv (-7)^8 \equiv 49^4 \equiv 85^2 \equiv 84 \pmod{193}$.

How to get it here and how can the power be reduced?

Comment: $46^2 \equiv 186 \equiv -7 \pmod{193}$.

Comment: You should understand why since it's your idea, and you get the final answer ;)

Comment: If it was your idea then who told you that it was $46^{16}\equiv (-7)^8...etc$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first we compute $5^8\,(mod193)$
az you computed: $$5^4\equiv46$$
therefore we have:$$5^8\equiv(-7)$$
$$5^{64}\equiv{(5^8)}^8\equiv{(-7)}^8\equiv7^8\equiv84\,(mod193)$$